Find the side of the square ABCD in the figure below
In the figure, ABCD is a square.
If $\dfrac{1}{BM^2}+\dfrac{1}{BN^2} = \dfrac{1}{25}$, calculate AB
(Answer: $AB=5$)

I try:
$\triangle ABN \sim \triangle DMN: \frac{MN}{BN} = \frac{MD}{L}=\frac{ND}{L+ND}$
$\triangle MBC:: L^2+MC^2 = MB^2$
$\triangle ABN: L^2+BN^2=(L+DN)^2$
$\triangle BCM \sim \triangle NDM: \frac{ND}{L}=\frac{DM}{MC}=\frac{MN}{BM}$
$\triangle MBC \sim \triangle NBA: \frac{BM}{BN}=\frac{L}{L+DN}=\frac{MC}{L}$

If $s$ is the side of the square, and $\theta := \angle N = \angle MBC$, then $|BM|=s\sec\theta$ and $|BN|=s\csc\theta$. So, ...

The first thing I thought, looking at the answer you gave, was $a^{-2} + b^{-2}  = c^{-2}$

Let $\theta = \measuredangle N = \measuredangle BCM$.
$\sin \theta = \frac {CM}{BM} = \frac {MD}{MN}=\frac {AB}{BN}$
While $\cos \theta=\frac  {BC}{BM}= \frac {DN}{MN} = \frac {AN}{BN}$ but as $BC = AB$ we have $\cos \theta = \frac {AB}{BM}$
So $(\frac {AB}{BM})^2 + (\frac {AB}{BN})^2 =1$
$AB^2 (\frac 1{BM^2} + \frac 1{BN^2}) =1$
So $AB = \sqrt{\frac 1{(\frac 1{BM^2} + \frac 1{BN^2})}}$
....
Neat thing is that will be true for any $N$ we choose.  We can't actually calculate $BM$ nor $BN$.

FYI, rather than m\angle BCM, which appears as $m\angle BCM$, you may instead wish to use \measuredangle BCM, which appears as $\measuredangle BCM$.

Ah, you are never too old to learn another mathjax command.  ... of course in my day way we had to walk uphill in the snow all our textbooks used $m \angle$ rather than $\measuredangle$ but... pretty is pretty.

Oh, we had steep hills in UC Santa Cruz (seriously we really did.  Crown-Merrill college especially).  And oh, the snow!  I can't begin to tell you about all the snow in Santa Cruz.  (Seriously.  I can't.  Literally.)

We will prove $\dfrac{1}{BM^2} + \dfrac{1}{BN^2} = \dfrac{1}{AB^2}$, or equivalently $\dfrac{1}{AB^2} - \dfrac{1}{BN^2} = \dfrac{1}{BM^2}$.
We have
$\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{AB^2} - \dfrac{1}{BN^2} &= \dfrac{BN^2 - AB^2}{BN^2 \cdot AB^2}\\
&= \dfrac{AN^2}{BN^2 \cdot AB^2}\\
&= \left( \dfrac{AN}{BN} \right)^2 \cdot \left( \dfrac{1}{AB} \right)^2\\
&= \left( \dfrac{BC}{BM} \right)^2 \cdot \left( \dfrac{1}{AB} \right)^2 \qquad \text{by } \triangle MBC \sim \triangle NBA\\
&= \dfrac{1}{BM^2}
\end{align}$
as desired. $\blacksquare$

You are starting from the solution. If we didn't know that the answer is 5, there is no way to assume that $\frac{1}{BM^2}+\frac{1}{BN?2}=\frac{1}{AB^2}$


The Pythagoras theorem on BN: BN² = AB² + AN²
replace AN with AB + DN
Thales's theorem will give relation between AB and DN (DN = AB * (BN/BM - 1))
after developing: BN² = AB² * (1 + BN²/BM²)
from equality given: 1 + BN²/BM² = BN²/25
hence AB² = 25²


I think the picture caused me to not trust the equation, in that it only showed a particular case of BM and BN.
The equation tells me that I can let BM and BN vary (as long as the original relationships shown are preserved, that is, DN is not negative) and it's still true.
So, I chose 2 different values for AN, AN = AB and AN = +$\infty$.
(I) AN = AB
(II) AN = $=\infty$
$\frac{1}{BM^2}+\frac{1}{BN^2}=\frac{1}{25}$
Plugging in those values and looking at BM and BN:
(I) BM = BN = $\sqrt{2}AB$
(II) BM = AB and BN goes to $\infty$
Now the equation can be re-written only in terms of AB:
(I) $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}AB^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}AB^2}=\frac{1}{25}$
and
(II) $\frac{1}{AB^2}+0=\frac{1}{25}$
Both can be solved and show the same result:
AB = 5
(Forgive the formatting etc... It's my first reply here.)

I agree with @fleablood (conditionally), you can't calculate BM or BN (exclusively), you can get them both though by choosing AN, and so agree with them again, that the value of N (sic) doesn't matter. (Don't know if AN < AB preserves the relationship)
